# Many to one entity using JPA

Tags: jpa, maven-2

I am trying to create an entity for the table structure given belos

```
(id, name, task, leader_id)
```

this table gives the information about the team users for the particular task and their leader for the team.

I wrote the entity like this

```
@Column(name = "id", insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = true)
private Integer id;

@Col umn(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String tokenName;

@Column(name = "task", nullable = false)
private String task;

@ManyToOne(cascade = ALL, fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "leader_id")
private User leader;
```

I created the ddl through hibernate3:hbm2ddl and it looks like this

```
alter table user
drop
foreign key FK60FD5D6395C4EEC2;

drop table if exists user;

create table user (
    id integer not null auto_increment,
    task varchar(255),
    name varchar(255) not null,
    leader_id integer,
    primary key (id)
);

alter table user
    add index FK60FD5D6395C4EEC2 (leader_id),
    add constraint FK60FD5D6395C4EEC2
    foreign key (leader_id)
    references user (id);
```

while exporting this schema through maven-sql-plugin, I am getting the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute:
alter table user
drop
foreign key FK60FD5D6395C4EEC2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Column "FOREIGN" not found; SQL statement:

alter table user
drop
foreign key FK60FD5D6395C4EEC2 [42122-158]
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems hbm2ddl is generating invalid SQL for your database. Are you sure you specified the appropriate dialect. What's your database, and which dialect did you specify?

Comment: @JB Nizet org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

Comment: @JB Nizet H2(Embedded database)

Comment: Then no idea. I checked the source code of H2Dialect, and it extends Dialect which returns " drop constraint " in the method getDropForeignKeyString. Maybe you're using an older version of Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = ALL, fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "leader_id")
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) 
public User getLeader()
{
  return leader;
}
```

Comment: Instead of having the mappings on a field declarations, try move the mappings on a getter properties, i.e `getLeader(){..}` etc.

Comment: Couldn't get you Bitmap. I also have getter and setter for this variable

Comment: @Gnanam move the mapping onto the getter methods.

Comment: It skips the error, but table is not created using foreign key reference

Comment: Try mapping the leader_id column separately both insertable & updatable set to false